# PHP fails fopen if the file is large

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm running an app on Google App Engine, on PHP.

I'm using the following code to download a file from an API:

```
$context = [
   "http" => [
   "method" => "GET",
   "header" => "Authorization: ".$token."\r\n",
   "follow_location"=>1,
   "timeout"=>600,
   "ignore_errors"=>1
              ]
            ];
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$sourceFile = fopen($location,"r", false,$context) or die("no handle");
```

This code is then followed by a chunk read and write to another resource (basically I'm storing the file on Google Storage).

```
$destinationFile = fopen($filename,"w");
while ($buffer = fread($sourceFile, 1048576)) {
      fwrite($destinationFile,$buffer);
}
```

The issue with this code is that it DOES work perfectly if the file is small (circa below 30 MB) but the fopen fails if the file is large. I have the "no handle" message.

It's kinda weird because I explictly avoided to use the file_get_contents to download the entire file in memory and I don't understand why fopen should fail!

Can you help me? thanks

Comment: Note also that this code, if executed locally (and not on Google App Engine) works perfectly even on large files. So it must be some configuration of App Engine...

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 32 megabytes. That is why it fails. The limit does not, apparently, apply locally, hence why it works on the dev server.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Python_Quotas_and_limits

Comment: But I'm not getting the full file with the request: I'm just getting an fopen and then read it in chunks. Are you saying that the HTTP request will get the full response?

If so, how am I supposed to get a large file from a API download request and post it on Google Storage? Any recommended method?

Thanks

Comment: well, it looks as if the HTTP request is getting the full response. I don't do PHP so not too much help. You can, in python, set "Accept-Ranges" and/or "Accept-Length" headers so presumably there is something similar in PHP to get partial content.

Comment: I tried adding `$rng= 'HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nContent-Range: bytes 0-7999999/37762382\r\nContent-Length: 8000000\r\n';` to the headers to get the first 8MB but it's not even working locally - maybe the API does not support resumable downloads - and by the way it does not even report the content-length

Comment: The external service may or may not respect those headers.

Comment: Ranges for streaming should work fine if the server your contacting supports them. We use the same URLFetch APIs in the cloud storage client we ship with the SDK and use range requests to support files of arbitrary length.